# Rotate CGImage taken from video frame

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-2d, avfoundation

This is Apple's code (from Technical Q&A QA1702) for getting a UIImage from a video buffer.  Unfortunately, the image returned is rotated 90 degrees.  How do I edit this so that the image returned is correctly oriented?

```
- (UIImage *) imageFromSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer 
{
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer); 
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0); 

    void *baseAddress = CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer); 

    size_t bytesPerRow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(imageBuffer); 
    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer); 
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer); 

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB(); 

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(baseAddress, width, height, 8, 
                                                 bytesPerRow, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst); 

    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); 
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    CGContextRelease(context); 
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage];

    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Depends on whether you are using the front camera or the back camera

```
int frontCameraImageOrientation = UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored;
int backCameraImageOrientation = UIImageOrientationRight;

UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:newImage scale:(CGFloat)1.0 orientation:frontCameraImageOrientation];
```

Comment: Thanks!  That worked great - with the slight correction of including the orientation: parameter label in the method call.

Comment: Awesome! and so simple, specially after a long fight with CG with no successful results, tks!

Comment: The image is still roated 90 degree anticlockwise

Comment: Awesome! Searching for exactly this hint.

Answer (score 3):

You can change videoOrientation, this way you get a correct image

```
connection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationPortrait
```

Because by default Video orientation is not portrait.

Answer (score 1):

#### Just rotate the context

Simply rotate the context in radians. This call would rotate the context 90 degrees.

```
CGFloat degrees = 90.f;
CGFloat radians = degrees * (M_PI / 180.f);
CGContextRotateCTM(context, radians);
```

You can easily set this method to take the desired orientation and rotate accordingly.